# How can you slidedown and slideup an element using ng-if in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, css

I have the following component.

```
<my-section
    ng-if="$ctrl.playerId"></my-section>
```

This playerId is dynamic.  When it doesn't exist I want this element to slideUp.  When it does - I want it to slideDown.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can bring in the ngAnimate module and take advantage of certain CSS classes which are applied when the DOM changes.

For `ng-if`, you'll want to look at `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` in particular.

Below's an example to demonstrate.

Don't forget to check out the [official documentation on animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.playerId = false;
  })
  .component('mySection', {
    template: '<pre>...</pre>',
  });
```

```css
my-section {
  background: silver;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
my-section.ng-enter,
my-section.ng-leave {
  transition: all ease-out .3s;
}
my-section.ng-enter,
my-section.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  height: 0;
}
my-section.ng-leave,
my-section.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.playerId">
  <my-section ng-if="$ctrl.playerId"><my-section>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```